# Is this sentence unneeded, or even detrimental?

Tags: academic-writing, word-choice, essay

I'm writing an essay, and I have in it this paragraph clip:

> "Finally, euphemisms are constantly used in both films in order to
> lessen the impact of what the American government was doing to
> Japanese Americans. These euphemisms were used in place of words that
> were much harsher sounding..."

Is the second sentence unneeded, since I essentially define the word euphemism?

Also, does it make my writing worse in a professional setting (the audience will know what a euphemism is when reading my essay)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a professional setting? A professional is someone who writes for money. That is, you have a job as a writer. Do you? If not, you are not working in a professional setting.

But I think in your last sentence ("Does it make my writing worse in a professional setting?") you actually mean: "Does it make my writing worse when I write for an educated or expert audience?"

And yes, it does.

You should always write for your target audience.

If you write for younger readers or the general public, you might need to explain what a euphemism is. If you write for an academic audience, explaining what they can be expected to know will become irritating.

Know who you are writing for and write for them. You cannot write for everyone at the same time.